# Google TV Picture in Picture

Tags: google-tv

I am aware that Live TV is the only gTV application that can run in PiP (Picture in Picture) mode.
My question is there anyway i can program my application, when invoked,  to always run with LiveTV as a frame inside?

I need to ensure that my application always runs with LiveTv as a frame inside!

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No official way - and the unofficial ways will not be supported in the future.

Comment: I guess it will a good feature. Wonder what makes you guys so against it!

Comment: As I understand it, it's a way to lower the cost of devices.